# How to programatically getting current users location to load on a map in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, geolocation, google-maps-flutter

Please help. I am trying to get the initialCameraPosition to programmatically display the current location of a user on a map. I don't want to hard code it.
I have a getCurrentLocation method but I can't seem to use the result (its lat and lon) as the latitude and longitude of the initialCameraPosition of the Map.

the getCurrentLocation method is

```
Future<Position> getCurrentPosition() async {
Position position = await Geolocator()
    .getCurrentPosition(desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.high);
print(position);
return position;
```

}

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(
  backgroundColor: Colors.white,
  body: Stack(
    children: <Widget>[
      GoogleMap(
        initialCameraPosition:
            CameraPosition(target: LatLng(9.0765, 7.3986), zoom: 17),//these coordinates should not be hard coded
        onMapCreated: _onMapCreated,
        myLocationEnabled: true,
        mapType: MapType.normal,
        markers: _marker,
      ),}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just wait to load user current location ;

**1 hit getCurrentPosition() from init() like**

```
Position position;

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    getCurrentPosition()
  }

  getCurrentPosition() async 
    {
    position = await Geolocator()
            .getCurrentPosition(desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.high);

    setState((){});
     
    }
```

**2. Now you build function will be like:**

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        body: position==null?CircularProgressIndicator(): Stack(
            children: <Widget>[
        GoogleMap( initialCameraPosition: CameraPosition(target:position.getLatLng, zoom: 17),

          onMapCreated: _onMapCreated,
          myLocationEnabled: true,
          mapType: MapType.normal,
          markers: _marker,

    )]));

  }
```

Comment: I did but they told me my reputation is still low that is why it did not appear. Kindly help me with this please. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62668759/getter-error-while-using-geofire-to-query

Comment: Did you solve your problem?  (ok, then no worry. you can also click on Tick  (about upvote) )

Comment: ✅ Done. I have not been able to solve the problem on the link. It's not querying